# Javascript bookmark stopped working in Firefox 13

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet, bookmarks

In Firefox version 13, bookmarklets (bookmarks with a `javascript:` URL, e.g. `javascript: alert("it works")` stopped working. Is there any solution to use `javascript:` bookmarks in Firefox 13?

Comment: As a user I have never used "add to bookmarks" link and I don't know anyone used it ever. Was always curious who this feature is implemented for?

Comment: No, it is not about "add to bookmark". That is just easy to do with clicking on star. I had javascript bookmark to fill a form. That stopped working.

Comment: Which page are you trying to run the bookmarklet on?

Comment: @zerkms I want if any new method has come for this.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky apparently this is only an issue when attempting to run in a new, non-URL-loaded tab.

Comment: yes @MichaelPaulukonis, I need to fill login form for my internet service provider every day. For that I was using js bookmark. If page was open then fill and submit or open page and complete process. But now I need to load page for that to work.

Comment: It's killing me, too. javascript-bookmarklets are the stuff of life!

Comment: The problem is back in FF41, and the solutions here no longer work. I have a question, and a potential answer (that I don't like) @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782860/javascript-bookmark-stopped-working-in-firefox-41

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a consequence of [Bug 728313 - Using a bookmark keyword to a bookmarklet fails on new tabs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=728313), also [Bug 739387 - Aurora 13a New Tab display doesn't allow javascript bookmarks to be selected](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739387) . This bug affects Firefox 13 onwards.

As a consequence of the fix to [bug 723808](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=723808), `javascript:` bookmarks are disabled in a just-created new tab. If you first load almost any URL, including `about:blank`, then a Javascript bookmark will work in that tab.

Note that this is about Javascript bookmarks (bookmarklets). You cannot use this workaround to load `javascript:` URLs typed directly in the location bar. These have been disabled since Firefox 6, as a consequence of [bug 656433](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656433) (phishing of `javascript:` URLs). [Bug 680302](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=680302) is a feature request to allow turning `javascript:` URLs back on through a preference. [Valadrem](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/31631/) has written the [InheritPrincipal extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inheritprincipal/) to remove this restriction (I haven't tested it). [You can still type and run Javascript code in the Scratchpad](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/917723) (press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, type code, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

There are restrictions on the Javascript you can run from the URL bar or from a bookmark. For example, since Firefox 7, you [cannot resize the window](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/885558#answer-259571) (consequence of the fix to [bug 565541](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565541)); the [`services.sync.prefs.sync.dom.disable_window_move_resize`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Resizing_oversize_window) controls this restriction.

Answer (score 7):

**NOTE:** this solution no longer appears to work as of FF41. See [JS Bookmarklets stopped working in Firefox 41](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782860/javascript-bookmark-stopped-working-in-firefox-41).

---

> If you first load almost any URL, including about:blank, then a
>   Javascript bookmark will work in that tab.

Since Firefox's default behavior for new tabs is `about:newtab`, which is *nothing*, and bookmarklets only run once *something* is loaded, you can do the following to set a default page, and then run bookmarklets:

1. open `about:config`
2. find `browser.newtab.url`
3. double-click and change from `about:newtab` to `about:blank` (or URI of your choice)
4. `Ctrl-T` and run bookmarklets in new tabs!

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to use bookmarklets in recent versions of firefox (I just tested a few on FF23). Two suggestions:

1. Replace spaces with %20. For instance, try your example bookmarklet code with  `javascript:alert("it%20works")` instead of `javascript:alert("it works")`
2. If this isn't enough, enclose the whole bookmarklet inside an anonymous function, so in your example, you'd write `javascript:((function(){alert("it%20works");})())`