# Javascript bookmarklet stopped working in Firefox 41

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet

In Firefox 41, bookmarklets (bookmarks with a `javascript:` URL, e.g. `javascript: alert("it works")`, run from a click or a keyword) stopped working. Is there any solution to use `javascript:` bookmarks in Firefox 41?

Previously seen, understood and solved in [Javascript bookmark stopped working in Firefox 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131871/javascript-bookmark-stopped-working-in-firefox-13/11523613):

> If you first load almost any URL, including about:blank, then a
>   Javascript bookmark will work in that tab.

Since Firefox's default behavior for new tabs is `about:newtab`, which is *nothing*, and bookmarklets only run once *something* is loaded, you can do the following to set a default page, and then run bookmarklets:

1. open `about:config`
2. find `browser.newtab.url`
3. double-click and change from `about:newtab` to `about:blank` (or URI of your choice)
4. `Ctrl-T` and run bookmarklets in new tabs!

### But this no longer works

I can only assume it's related to the `browser.newtabpage` setting activated by default. However, disabling the `newtabpage` features did not re-enable it.

Other reports of the issue, and solutions, online refer only to installing the [New Tab Override extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-override). **That does work** - but *is there another way, other than by installing an extension?*

Comment: It kinda sucks that it doesn't work, because I _do_ like the NewTabPage. But I use keyword-bookmarklets for custom searches, opening issue-tracker pages by number, etc etc etc. Can't live without 'em.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [ghacks](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/28/mozilla-removes-option-to-change-new-tab-page-from-firefox/), Mozilla wanted the feature removed from `about:config` and *only* re-settable via extension:

> The `browser.newtab.url` preference has no exposed UI, is not really
>   supported, and is abused by search hijackers. We should remove it and
>   encourage people using a non-default new tab page to install an add-on
>   instead.

So, unless policy reverses itself (unlikely, as this is not the first time Mozilla has removed `about:config` features and insisted they be replaced by extensions), **using an extension like [New Tab Override](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-override/) is the only option.**

---

UPDATE: If you install New Tab Override, you must configure it *first*, and manually add `about:blank` to the extension settings.